# Init new react native project and replace with a current react native project in App Store

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store

it is possible to create a new react-native project and replace it with a current react native project from the app store ?

The app will be the same but I want to create a new clean project.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, all you need to do is keep the app name and the identifier (com.companyname.appname) for ios and android same as the previous app and increment build and version numbers. Create the clean new app and add the build as update to both iOS and android stores.